# Delimiters in Vue 3.1+, getting started issues

Tags: vue.js

Im a little lost on this, Im trying to get started with Vue but I cannot seem to get the delimiters changed and working. Would someone be nice enough to take a look at this code and tell me if it looks like it should be working? Im using this with Django and need to change them. In addition, even experimenting with the basic tags but loading the HTML page manually in my browser doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas? I can confirm Vue is loading because I get the message in the console when it loads. I am loading this from the CDN.

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    el: '#table-div',
    compilerOptions: {
        delimiters: ["[[',']]"],
    },
    data(){
        return {
            objects: {},
            text: 'This is a test', 
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in case someone else runs into issues. My particular issue is that the scripts needed to be loaded outside the ending body tag in my base.html file. I was using a template with Django and I could not get it to work within the template fragment. Loading it in the main file after the `</body>` tag worked like it should. I'd also add that the new `compilerOptions` way of changing the delimiter works as intended as well in case anyone stumbles on this trying to change the delimiter for any version 3.1+.